# JQuery Datatables and ascx markup

Tags: jquery, .net

I'm working on a Sharepoint web app and I'm trying to position an element within a web part.  The web part has a jQuery Datatables grid in it and a button that fires off an Excel download of that grid, works fine.  I also need to incorporate a link that fires off a call to the code behind to download a different report.  Ideally, I'l like to find a way to have that link and the button next to each other but I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

```
<div ID="dFundingSummary" class="dashboardMainDiv">

<asp:ListView
    ID="lvFundingSummary"
    OnItemDataBound="lvFundingSummary_ItemDataBound" 
    runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblResearchArea" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PlName")%>'  runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblFundingGross" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FundingGross", "{0:c}")%>'  runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblEpriGross" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AllEpriGross", "{0:c}")%>'  runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" style="width: 100%">

            <thead>
                <tr style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <th style="width: 45%; padding-left: 0px; text-align:left; border: none">Research Area</th>
                    <th style="width: 15%; text-align:right; border: none">Gross</th>
                    <th style="text-align:right; border: none">All EPRI Gross</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
                <tr style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <td style="padding-left:0px; border: none"><b>Total(s)</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:10px; border: none"><b><asp:Label ID="lblTotalFunding" runat="server" /></b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:10px; border: none"><b><asp:Label ID="lblTotalEpriGross" runat="server" /></b></td>
                </tr>          
            </tfoot>

            <tbody runat="server">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </tbody>

        </table>                            
    </LayoutTemplate>          
</asp:ListView>

 <span id="ExportFullReport" runat="server">
     <a OnServerClick="ExportToExcel"  id="aFullExport" runat="server">Export Full Report</a>
     <img alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/ICXLSX.PNG" />
</span>

</div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {

           var table = $('#itemPlaceholderContainer').dataTable(
               {
                   "scrollY": "300px",
                   "scrollX": true,
                   "scrollCollapse": true,
                   "paging": false,
                   "autowidth": true,

                   dom: '<"toolbar"><"filterPad"f>rti<"floatRight"B><"clear">',
                   buttons: {
                       buttons: [
                           { extend: 'excel', text: 'Save as Excel', exportOption: { page: 'current' }, footer: true }
                       ]
                   }

               });

           $("div.toolbar").html('<h2>Funding Summary</h2>');

       });
 </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with jQuery.  Right after you initiate the datatables library use the .prependTo command to move your link before the excel button.

```
$("#ExportFullReport").prependTo("#IdOfContainerContainingSaveAsExcelButton");

$("div.toolbar").html('<h2>Funding Summary</h2>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the span with id "ExportFullReport" inside a div with 100% width and give style as float:right to the span

Comment: Close, I want to get it to the left of the "Save as Excel" button.  That's the catch, I'm trying to figure out how to get into the datatables markup.

Comment: In the buttons property there may be some template or html property also there including text.. u can also rearrange data table footer Dom position by giving some expressions .. check datatables.org for that

Comment: I went through that stuff, the catch here isn't so much the text as it is being able to insert a .NET element, so I can call the code behind.